# Draw a rectangle

Tags: lists, color, boxes, itemize

How to draw a highlighted box around a bulleted item.

Comment: Related Question: [Box around a few items in an itemize environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45912/box-around-a-few-items-in-an-itemize-environment).

Comment: You got two answers and did not accept one. Any special reason?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `color` package and `\colorbox`, like so:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Hello
\item \colorbox{yellow}{I rule}
\item World
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

If you meant something else by "highlighted box", let me know.

Comment: no.i want to outline the item using a rectangle and highlight it

Comment: Do you mean you want a framed box? Try `\fbox{Test}`

Framed and filled?

Comment: \fbox {\item {Test}} is not working.i also want to blink that rectangle

Comment: Put the `\fbox` after the `\item`: `\item \fbox{Text}`

I believe it blinks [if you convert it to HTML](http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/latex_advanced/node13.html)

Comment: i want to add bullet also inside the rectangle

Comment: Before itemize insert 

`\newlength\mybox
\settowidth{\mybox}{rule}
\addtolength{\mybox}{0.4in}`
then use
`\item \hspace{-0.25in}\framebox[\mybox][r]{Boxed text}`

Comment: please colour the rectangle and blink it

Answer (score 2):

Here a solution of the German forum  [MrUnix](http://mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?t=70017)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{picture,}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\fboxitem[1]{%
 \setlength\@tempdima{\itemsep}%
 \addtolength\@tempdima{\dimexpr\labelsep+\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax}%
 \item\leavevmode\put(-\the\@tempdima,0){%
  \fbox{\hspace*{\dimexpr\itemsep+\labelsep\relax}%
         \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax}{%
    #1}}}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen
\fboxitem{Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen Text im Rahmen}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]