# Problems using `\left\{` in array environment

Tags: errors, formatting, arrays

I am trying to define a matrix in segments by enclosing the entries of the matrix in boxes, and also using the open and closed braces to label those segments.  So far I have developed the following code to do this.

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\[
  A =
    \left(
      \begin{array}{rrrrrl}
          \cline{2-4} \cline{5-5}
        \multirow{2}{*}{$B \{$} &
          \multicolumn{1}{|r}{1} & 2 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-4} & \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{1} & \multirow{2}{*}{$\} \hat{\mathbf{b}}^{T}$} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{|r}{2} & -5 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{-3} & \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{-3} & \\
          \cline{2-4} \cline{5-5}
        \hat{\mathbf{c}} \{  & \multicolumn{1}{|r}{-6} & -3 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{5} & \} a_{n-1,n} \\
          \cline{2-4} \cline{5-5}
        \hat{\mathbf{d}} \{ & \multicolumn{1}{|r}{-6} &  7 & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{-8} & \} a_{n,n} \\
          \cline{2-4} \cline{5-5}
      \end{array}
    \right)
\]


\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

What I want to do is expand the left and right brace in the first and last columns to line up with the rows that have been segmented.  One way of doing this is to use the `\left\{` and `\right\}` LaTeX commands.  The problem is that when I do this, I get the following LaTeX error:

```
! Missing \right.  inserted.
<inserted text>
                \right .
l.12         \multirow{2}{*}{$B \left\{$}
                                          &
?
```

Also, what I would like to do is separate the segments using individual boxes, rather than adjoining boxes as above.  Any ideas on how to do this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the package `blkarray`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel - Thanks for that.  I presume that resolves my second problem?

Comment: would you be open to using `tikz` for the boxing?

Comment: @cmhughes - Indeed I would!  I am currently using `tikz` for some of the lattice graphs.

Comment: the "headroom" between digits and the rules above them is terribly uneven and mostly too tight.  the `array` package provides the command `\extrarowheight` to make adjustments of this sort; alternatively, a `\vphantom{...}` with some suitable content (maybe `$\hat X$`) could be applied in the rows that need it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I took @mico's answer and added `hhline`

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{multirow,hhline}
\begin{document}
  \[
  A =
  \left(
  \begin{array}{r|rrr||r|l}
    \hhline{~|---||-|~}
    \multirow{2}{*}{$B \bigg\{$} 
    & 1 & 2 & -4 & 1 & 
    \multirow{2}{*}{$\bigg\} \hat{\mathbf{b}}^{T}$} \\
    & 2 & -5 & -3 & -3 & \\
    \hhline{~:===::=:~}
    \hat{\mathbf{c}} \{  & -6 & -3 & 0 & 5 & \} a_{n-1,n} \\
    \hhline{~:===::=:~}
    \hat{\mathbf{d}} \{ & -6 &  7 & 0 & -8 & \} a_{n,n} \\
    \hhline{~|---||-|~}
  \end{array}
  \right)
  \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Bill: And you might want to replace `\begin{array}{r|rrr||r|l}` by `\begin{array}{@{}r@{}|rrr|r|@{}l@{}}` to get rid of the horizontal space between the braces and the boxes.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks for that David and Stephen!  It seems to be the simplest solution that allows me to do both!

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution using the tried and tested `\tikzmark` idea, first show cased in Andrew Stacey's answer to

[Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/adding-a-large-brace-next-to-a-body-of-text)

[image]

The code below uses a version modified from Peter Grill's answer to

[Box around a few items in an itemize environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45912/box-around-a-few-items-in-an-itemize-environment/45926#45926)

My solution is a little bit fiddly- there's a bit of manual column and row spacing, and a couple of uses of `\vphantom` so that instead of using `\bigg` you can use `\left\{...\right.` but the output is (I hope) quite pleasing.

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand{\DrawBox}[3][]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
        \coordinate (RightPoint) at (#3.east);
    \draw[red,#1]
      ($(#2)+(-.5em,.9em)$) rectangle
      ($(RightPoint)+(0.2em,-0.3em)$);}
}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\begin{document}

\[
  A =
    \left(
    \begin{array}{r@{\hspace{.2cm}}c@{}rrr@{\hspace{.5cm}}r@{}rl}
       \multirow{2}{*}{$B \left\{\vphantom{\begin{array}{c}1\\2\end{array}}\right.$} 
                                &\tikzmark{left1}   & 1   & 2  & -4                     &\tikzmark{left3}   & 1  & 
                                \multirow{2}{*}{$\left.\vphantom{\begin{array}{c}1\\2\end{array}}\right\} \hat{\mathbf{b}}^{T}$} \\
                                &                   & 2   & -5 & -3\tikzmark{right1}    &                   &-3 \tikzmark{right3}   & \\[5pt]
        \hat{\mathbf{c}} \{     &\tikzmark{left2}   & -6  & -3 & 0 \tikzmark{right2}    &\tikzmark{left4}   & 5  \tikzmark{right4}  &\}a_{n-1,n} \\[5pt]
        \hat{\mathbf{d}} \{     &\tikzmark{left5}   & -6  &  7 & 0 \tikzmark{right5}    &\tikzmark{left6}   & -8 \tikzmark{right6}  & \} a_{n,n} \\
      \end{array}
    \right)
\]

\DrawBox[thick,green,fill=yellow,fill opacity=0.1]{left1}{right1}
\DrawBox[thick,blue]{left2}{right2}
\DrawBox[thick,red]{left3}{right3}
\DrawBox[thick,purple]{left4}{right4}
\DrawBox[thick,yellow]{left5}{right5}
\DrawBox[thick,orange]{left6}{right6}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for that!  It does exactly what I want and more!  For the moment, though, I will stick to David's solution as it seems much simpler, and easier to adapt to my example.  You might, however, want to post your solution to [http://www.texample.net/tikz/](http://www.texample.net/tikz/), as they are always looking for TikZ examples.  I believe the page is moderated by [Stefan Kottwitz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/213/stefan-kottwitz), who is also a member of this group.

Comment: It might be a good idea to include the `\DrawBox` commands inside the math environment rather than following it.  I had to do this when the "array" was the last thing included on a given page; the coloured boxes were drawn on the next page in that case - unless I include the `\DrawBox` instructions inside the `\[ ... \]`

Comment: @André thanks, that's a good idea. I'll make an edit in a couple of days

Answer (score 5):

You could use the explicit size statement `\bigg` in order to set the size of the left and right curly braces, as is shown in the following modified form of your MWE. To get the arrays display with a little gap while using the `\cline` command, it's necessary to break them up into two separteI've also simplified the code to get rid of most of the `\multicolumn` statements and combining the various paired `\cline` statements.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}      
  \[
  A =
  \left(
  \begin{array}{r|rrr|}
    \cline{2-4} 
    \multirow{2}{*}{$B \bigg\{$} 
    & 1 &  2 & -4  \\ 
    & 2 & -5 & -3 \\
    \cline{2-4} 
    \hat{\mathbf{c}} \{  & -6 & -3 & 0 \\
    \cline{2-4}
    \hat{\mathbf{d}} \{  & -6 &  7 & 0 \\
    \cline{2-4} 
  \end{array}
  \right. \kern-3pt \left. % use \kern-3pt to reduce distance between arrays
  \begin{array}{|r|l}
    \cline{1-1}
     1 & \multirow{2}{*}{$\bigg\} \hat{\mathbf{b}}^{T}$} \\
    -3 & \\
    \cline{1-1}
     5 & \} a_{n-1,n} \\
    \cline{1-1}
    -8 & \} a_{n,n} \vphantom{\hat{\mathbf{d}}}\\  
        % the \vphantom is needed to equalize the heights of the 
        % third rows across the two arrays
    \cline{1-1}
  \end{array}
  \right)
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that.  Any idea on how I would separate the boxes?

Comment: Do you mean the first three number columns versus the fourth column?

Comment: I mean all of them.  That is, each segment would be separated by its own box if that makes any sense.

Comment: Bill -- I've amended my code to produce two separate arrays. Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I added a version of this using hhline

Comment: @Mico - Thanks Mico!  It was partly what I was looking for, but David's solution was exactly what I was looking for.  I believe he elaborated on the example that you provided using `\hhline`.  Mind you, I also like the `tikz` solution also!