# add frame to matrix

Tags: math-mode, boxes, matrices, framed

I want to enclose my matrix by a box. I have followed the instructions in this 
[link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45912/box-around-a-few-items-in-an-itemize-environment/)
but couldnt get the borders correct. Here is how the frame looks like and the code.

[image]

```
\begin{frame}
\medskip\par\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
\newcommand*{\WidestText}{
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\[0.3em]\end{bmatrix}.*
\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\[0.3em]
2 \\[0.3em]
1 \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}
=\text{ERROR} 
}%
\tikzmark{left}
{\footnotesize
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\[0.3em]\end{bmatrix}.*
\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\[0.3em]
2 \\[0.3em]
1 \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}
=\text{ERROR} 
\]
}
{\footnotesize
\[\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\[0.3em]
2 \\[0.3em]
3 \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}
.*
\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\[0.3em]
2 \\[0.3em]
1 \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\[0.3em]
4 \\[0.3em]
3 \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}
\]
}
\makebox[\widthof{\WidestText}][l]{  }\tikzmark{right}
\DrawBoxWide[thick, brown]
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: I followed a link which was a question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45912/box-around-a-few-items-in-an-itemize-environment/ but could not get the desired output.

Comment: Or just \fbox and array.  Array is like tabular in that you have to specify each column alignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example with `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\[0.3em]\end{bmatrix}.*
\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\[0.3em]
2 \\[0.3em]
1 \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}
=\text{ERROR} 
\]

\[\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\[0.3em]
2 \\[0.3em]
3 \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}
.*
\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\[0.3em]
2 \\[0.3em]
1 \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\[0.3em]
4 \\[0.3em]
3 \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{tcolorbox}

\tcboxmath{
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\[0.3em]\end{bmatrix}.*
\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\[0.3em]
2 \\[0.3em]
1 \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}
=\text{ERROR} 
}

\tcboxmath{
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\[0.3em]
2 \\[0.3em]
3 \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}
.*
\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\[0.3em]
2 \\[0.3em]
1 \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\[0.3em]
4 \\[0.3em]
3 \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]